# Usar função de arquivo externo sem dar include

Tags: php, include

Tenho uma função `getHeader()` no arquivo `include.php`.

É possível chamar essa respectiva função no meu arquivo `index.php` sem precisar dar um `include`, parecido com o Wordpress?

Comment: Não sei se entendi. Você quer chamar uma função que está em um arquivo sem nunca incluir/carregar esse arquivo?

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível devido à tabela de símbolos.

#### Tabela de símbolos

A tabela de símbolos define o contexto nas linguagens de programação. Variáveis, funções, classes, objetos, constantes, etc terão uma referência armazenada na tabela de símbolos quando definidas e, dentro de um contexto, só é possível utilizar os itens referenciados na tabela.

#### Contexto de variáveis

Não fez sentido? Vejamos um exemplo.

```
$x = "Variável X";
$y = "Variável Y";

function myFunction ()
{
  return "Função myFunction";
}
```

No arquivo `index.php` definimos duas variáveis e uma função. Podemos verificar a tabela de símbolos referente às variáveis utilizando a função [`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-defined-vars.php):

```
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

O retorno será algo como:

```
Array
(
    [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    [_POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
        )

    ...

    [x] => Variável X
    [y] => Variável Y
)
```

Perceba que todas as variáveis de escopo global do PHP também são retornadas, pois, pertencendo ao escopo global, estarão presentes em todas as tabelas de símbolos, independente do contexto. Para fins didáticos, vamos remover as variáveis globais, de forma a exibir apenas as variáveis que declaramos:

```
$_globals = get_defined_vars();

$x = "Variável X";
$y = "Variável Y";

...

print_r(array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $_globals));
```

Neste caso, a saída será apenas:

```
Array
(
    [x] => Variável X
    [y] => Variável Y
)
```

Ou seja, as variáveis `$x` e `$y` pertencem ao contexto atual e, por isso, são definidas na tabela de símbolos. Agora, se alterarmos o contexto, por exemplo, chamando uma função e verificarmos a tabela de símbolos do novo contexto:

```
$_globals = get_defined_vars();

$x = "Variável X";
$y = "Variável Y";

function myFunction ()
{
  global $_globals;
  print_r(array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $_globals));
  return "Função myFunction";
}
```

O retorno será uma lista vazia. Isso porque as variáveis não fazem mais parte do contexto.

```
Array
(
)
```

Se definirmos uma variável interna à função:

```
function myFunction ()
{
  global $_globals;
  $z = "Variável Z";
  print_r(array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $_globals));
  return "Função myFunction";
}
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [z] => Variável Z
)
```

Pois `$z` é a única variável existente no contexto atual. Saindo da função, ao verificarmos novamente a tabela de símbolos, teremos o mesmo resultado que no início, com as variáveis `$x` e `$y`, pois retornamos ao mesmo contexto. A variável `$z` deixa de existir por ela era uma variável local à função e só existirá dentro do contexto da mesma.

#### Contexto de funções

Se fizermos a mesma análise, mas agora verificando as funções existentes no contexto, através da função [`get_defined_functions`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-defined-functions.php), veremos para o contexto do arquivo:

```
$x = "Variável X";
$y = "Variável Y";

function myFunction ()
{
  return "Função myFunction";
}

print_r(get_defined_functions());
```

Temos a saída:

```
Array
(
    [internal] => Array
        (
            [0] => zend_version
            [1] => func_num_args
                ...
            [1074] => xmlwriter_output_memory
            [1075] => xmlwriter_flush
            [1076] => dl
            [1077] => cli_set_process_title
            [1078] => cli_get_process_title
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => handle_fatal
            [1] => output
            [2] => error_handler
            [3] => myFunction
        )
)
```

O que nos interessa é a parte final, identificado pelo índice `user`, onde encontra-se a função `myFunction`, que definimos no programa. Se verificarmos agora a tabela de símbolos para as funções dentro da função:

```
$x = "Variável X";
$y = "Variável Y";

function myFunction ()
{
  print_r(get_defined_functions());
  return "Função myFunction";
}
```

O resultado será **exatamente** o mesmo. Isso se dá ao fato que em PHP as funções pertencem ao escopo global, existindo em qualquer parte do programa, uma vez que a mesma é definida.

#### Respostas

**Mas por quê, então, eu não consigo fazer a chamada de uma função definida em outro arquivo sem fazer o include do mesmo?**

Pelo fato que se não haver o include ao arquivo onde a função é definida, o mesmo não será executado pelo PHP e a função nunca estará definida na tabela de símbolos.

**Mas estou usando o Wordpress e não preciso dar include em arquivos para chamar as funções. Por quê?**

Isso se dá ao fato que o Wordpress faz o "trabalho sujo" para você. Toda a programação que você faz é em um dos arquivos do tema da ferramenta: `page.php`, `single.php`, etc. Esses arquivos não tratam a requisição HTTP diretamente. Quem faz isso é o próprio arquivo `index.php` do Wordpress e, neste arquivo (ou em algum outro, seguindo a linha de execução), os arquivos do tema são incluídos. Neste caso, o contexto que você está trabalhando nos arquivos do tema existem as funções que são definidas em outro arquivo, mas porque o Wordpress fez com que existissem.

Nada acontece por mágica.

Comment: doideira mesmo rsrs

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguires utilizar funções de um outro ficheiro php terás de o incluir, seja utilizando include, require ou seja la o que for, tal como o wordpress o faz, podem tu não sabes é onde...

O ficheiro **wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php**, tem a função lá criada e o **wp-settings.php** faz o require desse mesmo ficheiro em 
`require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php' );` na linha 226... 
Como vez, não é possível fazer o que tu queres

[Link para código do wordpress no Github](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress)

Comment: entendi, então como não sou expert no php, muito meno no wordpress achei que ele dava um jeito de fazer um get sem include, mas como explicou ele implicitamente em algum arquivo ele faz essa configuração, é isso?

Comment: sim, desta maneira ou de outra, esses "imports" são feitos

Comment: A meu ver, o que fica melhor é a utilização de namespaces

Answer (score 1):

### Não, mas da para esconder.

Não há como não incluir o outro arquivo, entretanto existe como esconder ele, assim não exigindo adicionar o `include(...)` sempre em seu código.

Um exemplo é usar o `auto_prepend_file` no PHP.ini:

```
auto_prepend_file=C:\caminho\para\funcao.php
```

---

Isso irá fazer um `require` do arquivo definido (*ou seja, não é "sem dar include"*). Porém, o seu código estará sem qualquer tipo de `include(...)`, por exemplo:

*funcao.php*

```
function teste(){
    return 'Isso é um teste';
}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

echo teste();
```

Uma vez definido o `auto_prepend_file=C:\caminho\para\funcao.php` sempre o `C:\caminho\para\funcao.php` será incluído *implicitamente* em todas as páginas, isso vai fazer funcionar o `index.php`. ;)

---

> Sempre defina caminhos absolutos, não defina como `auto_prepend_file=funcao.php`, pois isso vai incluir o `funcao.php` da mesma pasta. Logo, acessar o `/www/index.php` vai incluir o `/www/funcao.php`, mas se acessar do `/www/pasta/index.php` irá incluir o `/www/pasta/funcao.php`.

Comment: ah ta! Tipo predefinido antes só pra depois usar, no caso do linux, então seria o caminho /var/www/sistema/include ?

Comment: Sim, no linux também deve especificar todo o caminho do arquivo, `/var/www/sistema/include/arquivo.php`.